# C# copy paste an image region into another image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmapimage

I am trying to write an utility class that permits automatic resizing of images that are tilebale. Let's say there is a srcBitmap from where I copy a region given by a Rectangle srcRegion. I then want to paste (pixel information wise) that region into another image called Bitmap destBitmap, in a destination region Rectangle destRegion.
I know how to get the region from the source and put it into a Bitmap object, but I haven't yet been able to find how to actually paste a Bitmap object in a certain region, inside another, bigger Bitmap object.

Is there a quick way to do this? (without GDI and without delving into the byte array of the Bitmaps). Here is the snippet that should clarify my goal

```
    private static void CopyRegionIntoImage(Bitmap srcBitmap, Rectangle srcRegion, Bitmap destBitmap, Rectangle destRegion)
    {
        // get the required region from the destination
        Bitmap region = Copy(srcBitmap, srcRegion);
    }
```

Comment: You're already using GDI+ with the Bitmap class.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the .Net 4.0 framework has wrappers around this library. wasn't aware of it, C# and dotNet aren't my bread and butter.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use this :

```
    public static void CopyRegionIntoImage(Bitmap srcBitmap, Rectangle srcRegion,ref Bitmap destBitmap, Rectangle destRegion)
    {
        using (Graphics grD = Graphics.FromImage(destBitmap))            
        {
            grD.DrawImage(srcBitmap, destRegion, srcRegion, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, you were faster and better. Hadn't seen that overload xD

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the overload either! Hope it will help other people as well. Best regards!

Comment: I think you don't need the "ref" key since you are not changing the destBitmap object.